# Why, when I convert a string into binary, does it miss the first zeros?

Tags: php

I try to convert any string into binary. But if binary start with zeros, it doesn't display it. All my test give me the binary value from the first 1 until end. Here my code :

```php
$value = unpack('H*', $MESSAGE);    
$binary .= base_convert($value[1], 16, 2);
```

For example when I tried to convert the character "%" it display : 100101 instead of : 00100101

Did I forget something?

Thanks.
Yacine

Comment: because it's treating it as 0, which can be omitted in most cases, e.g. 01 = 1. You'll need additional checks in place

Comment: @treyBake $binary is a string not a int

Comment: wait - did you var_dump() $value to check the actual value?

Comment: and where and how do yout output $binary

Comment: @treyBake yes and it's 25 for "%"

Comment: To display my value I just use an echo

Comment: `base_convert()` won't guess what binary size you want. `base_convert(1, 16, 2)` will be '1', which is as true as '00000001'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add zeros to the left of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021466/how-to-add-zeros-to-the-left-of-a-number)

Comment: @ThierryLeroux Thanks, I understand why zeros aren't displayed.

Comment: @aynber it's a string not a number but I think I found a solution with the link. Thank you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to see that the question boils down to the following:

> Why `base_convert($value[1], 16, 2)` does not zero-pad the result?

The reason is that `base_convert` interprets the first argument as a number (not a string of bytes, for example); it stops converting the bytes after the most significant bit is reached:

```
static char digits[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char buf[(sizeof(zend_ulong) << 3) + 1];
char *ptr, *end;
zend_ulong value;

if (Z_TYPE_P(arg) != IS_LONG || base < 2 || base > 36) {
    return ZSTR_EMPTY_ALLOC();
}

value = Z_LVAL_P(arg);

end = ptr = buf + sizeof(buf) - 1;
*ptr = '\0';

do {
    *--ptr = digits[value % base];
    value /= base;
} while (ptr > buf && value);

return zend_string_init(ptr, end - ptr, 0);
```

(i.e. when the `value` becomes zero.) The behavior is correct, since it is possible to add any number of zeroes up after the most significant bit without changing the result, e.g. `100101` is equal to `00100101`.

The function does not have a parameter that affects the formatting of the result. So, in order to achieve the desired output, you need to use other function(s) such as `sprintf`.